# What is the significance of the output of cat /etc/group?

Tags: permissions, users, groups

When I run `cat /etc/group` on Ubuntu 18.04, I get this output:

```
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:syslog,singrium
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
mail:x:8:
news:x:9:
uucp:x:10:
man:x:12:
proxy:x:13:
kmem:x:15:
dialout:x:20:
fax:x:21:
voice:x:22:
cdrom:x:24:singrium
floppy:x:25:
tape:x:26:
sudo:x:27:singrium
audio:x:29:pulse
dip:x:30:singrium
www-data:x:33:
backup:x:34:
operator:x:37:
list:x:38:
irc:x:39:
src:x:40:
gnats:x:41:
shadow:x:42:
utmp:x:43:
video:x:44:
sasl:x:45:
plugdev:x:46:singrium
staff:x:50:
games:x:60:
users:x:100:
nogroup:x:65534:
systemd-journal:x:101:
systemd-network:x:102:
systemd-resolve:x:103:
input:x:104:
crontab:x:105:
syslog:x:106:
messagebus:x:107:
netdev:x:108:
mlocate:x:109:
ssl-cert:x:110:
uuidd:x:111:
avahi-autoipd:x:112:
bluetooth:x:113:
rtkit:x:114:
ssh:x:115:
lpadmin:x:116:singrium
whoopsie:x:117:
scanner:x:118:saned
saned:x:119:
pulse:x:120:
pulse-access:x:121:
avahi:x:122:
colord:x:123:
geoclue:x:124:
gdm:x:125:
hani:x:1000:
sambashare:x:126:singrium
nvidia-persistenced:x:127:
rdma:x:128:
docker:x:999:
```

I know that 'root', 'daemon', etc. .. are groups or user names, but what does the rest of that mean (`:x:0:`, `:x:125:`, `:x:126:`, ...)?

Comment: Have you read the fine manual page (`man group`)?

Comment: @steeldriver since the answer is obvious and exists in `man group`, I don't know whether to let this question or to remove it. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting the respective manual page `man group`:

```
NAME
       group - user group file

DESCRIPTION
       The  /etc/group file is a text file that defines the groups on the sys‐
       tem.  There is one entry per line, with the following format:

              group_name:password:GID:user_list

       The fields are as follows:

       group_name  the name of the group.

       password    the (encrypted) group password.  If this field is empty, no
                   password is needed.

       GID         the numeric group ID.

       user_list   a  list  of  the  usernames that are members of this group,
                   separated by commas.
```

Comment: Maybe this post on U&L about the [Typical use case for a group password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93123/251553) is of interest. To summarize: _none_.